# Ubuntu 15.10 Graphics Glitching

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

I had Ubuntu 15.10 running on an old Dell SFF tower (I think a optiplex 755).
It uses integrated intel graphics.

Both with a monitor attached and thru screen sharing into the computer I see the following glitching:

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/5o0tgmboj/glitch.png]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to fix this?

I tried installing drivers form 01.org but I don't think that did anything.